# Javascript timer updates to slow after resuming app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple stopwatch timer included in my Ionic app (Android). I basically just save the start date, and then check every second (`mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);`) how many seconds it's been since that time. This works fine, but whenever I press the home button and then reopen the app (resume), it shows the old time for a fraction of a second, before updating to the new time. This does't happen when you exit the app and reopen it, because then it just calculates the new time.

Anyone who can help me with this? Any help is appreciated.

Update: countdown code:

```
$scope.onTimeout = function() {
   $scope.clock=Math.trunc(timeleft());
   mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
};

//timer counts down from 60 seconds
function timeleft()
{
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var currentdateseconds = currentdate.getTime()/1000;
  var timeleft = 60 - (currentdateseconds - window.localStorage['seconds']);
  return timeleft;
}
```

Comment: Hard to fix code issues when we can't see the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some code.

Comment: reduce the timeout value from 1000 to something like 100 or 200. If you want to optimize, you can call $timeout(fn, value, false) and call $scope.$apply only when there is an effective change. Does it mitigate your problem?

Comment: Won't changing the timeout value speed the counter up? Could you please elaborate on the optimization part? I'm new to Angular so I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: It seems that when resuming Android does not recalculate the screen objects (a 'mechanical' problem you wont be able to fix).  If it were me I'd update the timer to blank in the activity onPause method.. or equivalent, whatever event fires as the app is sent to the background. .

Comment: Don't think there is enough code to fix your problem. We can't see the code for what happens when you click the home button or what happens when you re-open the app. So I can only guess when you click on your home button, the `$scope.clock` variable doesn't get cleared or it gets initialized to some cached value when you reopen. And you might want to use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `$timeout` for your purposes

Comment: I'm not using any code to set behavior for clicking the home button or re-opening the app, so I guess it uses the default used by Ionic/cordova. I've tried setting the clock to blank on resume (using `$ionicPlatform.on("resume", function(event) {$scope.clock="";});` ). This clears to clock but it happens a fraction after re-opening the app, so my guess is that the resume-event is called just a fraction after resuming... I also tried changing "resume" to "pause", to force it to do this on pause (like clicking the home button), but in this case, it doesn't stay cleared...